# Post to Facebook Page from ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, facebook

How to post something on a facebook page's wall from a asp.net website.

Google search says that I have to create an app to do this. Is it possible to post to facebook wall without creating an app?

not sure where to start. I tried developers.facebook.com and csharpsdk.org. Not much luck. Is there an example? or a tutorial using the graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an APP on facebook is a minimum requirement for FB to accept your posts. What you are asking doesnt make much sense. Imagine if anyone can post stuff to FB, we probably wouldnt be discussing about this here (it would have been dead by now and I am glad it is how it is) I suggest you read these links for a quick start

- FB API in general:
  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/
- C# SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/
- Graph Api: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Hope this gives some starting points. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

After you create the application stuff in facebook and get your unique application id and secret code use the following (code behind)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        readonly static string myurl = "your url";
        readonly static string App_ID = "Your application id";
        readonly static string App_Secret = "your secret code";
        readonly static string scope = "email";
        FacebookUser me;
        readonly static DataContractJsonSerializer userSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FacebookUser));


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["code"] == null)
            {
                fbLogin.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                fbLogin.Visible = false;
            }
        }


        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if ((!IsPostBack) || Session["code"] == null)
            {
                string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
                if (code == null)
                {
                    Session["code"] = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["code"] = code;

                   // oAuth = new oAuthFacebook();
                   //// oAuthFacebook oFB = new oAuthFacebook();
                   // //Response.Redirect(oFB.AuthorizationLinkGet());
                   // oAuth.AccessTokenGet(Request["code"]);
                   // if (oAuth.Token.Length > 0)
                   // {
                   //     //We now have the credentials, so we can start making API calls
                   //     string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=" + oAuth.Token;
                   //     string json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
                   // } 


                }


                string error_description = Request.QueryString["error_description"];
                string originalReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]; // asp.net logon param
                Uri backHereUri = Request.Url; // modify for dev server
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)) // user is authenticated
                {
                    me = GetUserDetails(code, backHereUri);
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(me.email, false); // authorize!
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalReturnUrl))
                        Response.Redirect(originalReturnUrl);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error_description)) // user propably disallowed
                {
                    OnError(error_description);
                }

                fbLogin.Visible = !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
                {
                    fbLogin.Visible = true;
                    LoginName1.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    fbLogin.Visible = false;
                    LoginName1.Visible = true;
                    LoginName1.Text = "User Email: " + me.email.ToString() + " Name: " + me.first_name.ToString() + " Sname: " + me.last_name.ToString() + " Verified: " + me.verified.ToString();
                }

                fbLogin.NavigateUrl = string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                    + "client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri={2}",
                    App_ID,
                    scope,
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(backHereUri.OriginalString));
            }

        }

        FacebookUser GetUserDetails(string code, Uri backHereUri)
        {
            Uri getTokenUri = new Uri(
                string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                + "client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}&redirect_uri={3}",
                App_ID,
                App_Secret,
                Uri.EscapeDataString(code),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(backHereUri.OriginalString))
                );
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string token = wc.DownloadString(getTokenUri);
                Session["token"] = token;
                Uri getMeUri = new Uri(
                    string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/me?{0}",
                    token)
                    );
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(getMeUri)))
                {
                    var me = (FacebookUser)userSerializer.ReadObject(ms);
                    return me;
                }
            }
        }

        void OnError(string error_description)
        {
            Controls.Add(new Label()
            {
                CssClass = "oauth-error",
                Text = error_description
            }
            );
        }

        [Serializable]
        class FacebookUser
        {
            public long id;
            public string name;
            public string first_name;
            public string last_name;
            public string link;
            public string email;
            public string timezone;
            public string locale;
            public bool verified;
            public string updated_time;
        }



        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://localhost:5064/default.aspx,http://www.facebook.com");
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            xml = xml.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "").Replace("links_getStats_response xmlns=\"http://api.facebook.com/1.0/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd\" list=\"true\"", "links_getStats_response"); 
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("links_getStats_response/link_stat");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string fullurls = xn["url"].InnerText;
                string likes = xn["like_count"].InnerText;
                string comment = xn["comment_count"].InnerText;
                string normalisedurls = xn["normalized_url"].InnerText;

            }

        }



public string WebRequests(string method, string url, string postData)
{

HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
string responseData = "";

webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
webRequest.UserAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent; 
webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
if (method == "POST")
{
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
//POST the data.
requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
try
{
requestWriter.Write(postData);
}
catch
{
throw;
}
finally
{
requestWriter.Close();
requestWriter = null;
}
}

responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);
webRequest = null;
return responseData;
}

public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
StreamReader responseReader = null;
string responseData = "";

try
{
responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch
{
throw;
}
finally
{
webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
responseReader.Close();
responseReader = null;
}

return responseData;
}



protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["code"] != null)
    {
        string urls = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?" + Session["token"];
        var json = WebRequests("POST", urls, "message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("" + TextBox1.Text));
    }
}





    }
}


AND for default.aspx


<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Log in with Facebook" id="fbLogin"/><br /><br />

        <asp:Label ID="LoginName1" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Likes And Comments" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="407px" Text="Testing Api by c# code"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Post To me" 
            onclick="Button2_Click" />
    </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Try to format your post better and explain your code. When you are new to it, you have no clue what your code is doing, so the OP probably won't know what to do with this.

Comment: code is nice to implement facebook authentication, i use this code work good